# Salesforce - Prevent developer from accessing client base

Tags: database, salesforce, privacy, administrator

We've been developing a complete Salesforce overhaul for my organization, and have been using a 3rd party developer firm for all Sandbox customization. We're rolling out phase one on Monday, which involves importing our existing client base (4000+ clients) into the system. Their information includes personal info like SSNs, DOBs, and payment information. I would still like to keep the 3rd party development team on board, but would like to keep them from accessing client information.

Obviously, his team has full admin privileges under one account. Is there a way I can have him continue to have developer privileges without having access to our client base?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience you have to limit access to the Production environment for 3rd party team and move development activities to a sandboxes(if you have, or to a developer org. if you haven't sandboxes). You can use [any type of sandboxes](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create_test_instance.htm&language=en_US) excluding Full Copy Sandbox. Data for a sandboxes should be obfuscated before loading to development environment. Also you can create a set of triggers for obfuscating sensitive data on Full Copy sandboxes sandboxes which might be added as managed package to the sandbox which should be obfuscated. I guess that creating a set of such triggers should not take many time.